# How to display/alter a jailbroken iOS device's route table?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I jailbroke my iPhone4 and want to display and alter the route table on my iPhone. There is a `route` command, but I don't know the parameters needs to display/alter the route table.

I've googled a lot but still cannot find a clue. I know how to display/alter route table in Linux, but obviously the `route` command in iOS is not like the same command in Linux. Hope someone can answer this question.

Note: the iOS is the iOS of Apple, not the IOS of Cisco :-)

This command comes from package _network_cmds_ in Cydia.

The default output without any argument:
yeglemato-iPhone:~ root# route
usage: route [-dnqtv] command [[modifiers] args]

Comment: I cant remember, does the iphone even have man pages? Was this route command installed as a part of the jailbreak? What happens when you run it with no parameters? Even if it isnt the same command it probably behaves similarly.

Comment: @hobs This command is installed when you install Cydia on your phone, in package _network_cmds_. There seems no manpages in Cydia. I've updated the info in my question :-)

Comment: Yeah I think you just have the bsd version of route, I dont know how to use it much, but the man page is http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=route, thats the same route command if you type it into your mac.

Comment: This looks like a more user friendly intro to route on bsd http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-setup-default-routing-with-route-command/

Answer (score 3):

Use `netstat -r` to display route table and `route` to alter it.

You can read `netstat` and `route` man page on OSX for more information. I think they are the same BSD route version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't notice this is a BSD version of route/netstat :-)  Here's the manpage of MacOSX route/netstat command: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/route.8.html